# What does setDoc function return?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase

I'm using firebase in my reactjs+typescript project. I want to write a document in firebase and I'm using `setDoc` to do this job.

```
import { doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

setDoc(doc(database, `path`), objData)
```

When you check the function return it says `Promise<...>`. But, how am I supposed to use `then()` `catch()` promise handlers if I don't know what the promise returns when it fullfil/reject?

Comment: Often when it is a promise the `.then()` will have a `result` and then `.catch()` will have an error. So you would want to add a `.then(result)` and then do something with that, perhaps `.then(result -> {...})`

Comment: I never used firestore, but isn't this [the related documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#setdoc)? It clearly says `export declare function setDoc<T>(reference: DocumentReference<T>, data: WithFieldValue<T>): Promise<void>;`, what is so difficult here?

Comment: Firestore's [`setDoc`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#setdoc) returns a `Promise<void>`, so there's no result in the `then()`. The `catch` will get an error, as FivePaperFly says and the `then` gets no argument - it being called simply signals that the promise was successfully completed.

Comment: yea I know that but when I try `then(result => result)` result has `void` typo!! hahahaha some Promises has the type of its return in generic, aka: `Promise<onSucessType>`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen In my opinion, it could return the document ref onSuccess.... no? hahaha

Comment: @jgsneves that it because it does not return a value as the `.then()` simply signifies that the `setDoc()` succeeded. You are getting void because that is what it returns, void, nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Firebase but after looking around it seems the return is just going to be whether or not the `setDoc()` was successful. So the `.then()` would mean yes and the `.catch()` would mean no. So really all you would want is something like this

```
import { doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

setDoc(doc(database, `path`), objData)
.then(() => {
console.log("Successful")})
.catch((error) => {
console.log(`Unsuccessful returned error ${error}`)});
```

Again I am not fully sure about the exact values returned as I could not find much but if there is a result value given you would place it in the `.then((result) => {console.log(result)})`.

Comment: I had this same question but `result` is always undefined, even when successful (in 2023). I'm using await.

Comment: What happen when the user is offline? does It throw and exception?

Answer (score 1):

The firebase documentation suggest using `await`, so here you have a complete example of error handling with await and cleanup with finally.

```
import { doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';


async function run() {
    try {
        await setDoc(doc(database, `path`), objData)
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e); // handle your error here
    } finally {
        console.log('Cleanup here'); // cleanup, always executed
    }
}

run();
```

Comment: ty for answer! why use `async/await` and dont use `then().catch()` ?

Comment: Yes but you don't really want to use the try, catch. Since setDoc is a promise you need the `.then()` and `.catch()` to handle whether it was successful. Having a finally allows for the result to be skipped over which could lead to a missed insert.

Comment: In the firebase docs it uses await, but it's up to you :)

Comment: No it's not @FivePlyPaper, it's await for the result. Finally will get executed regardless, please try the code :)

Comment: @Wolfgang well im not trying it as I don't have it setup, finally does get executed regardless but still, a try catch just kind of wastes the point of it being a promise, it seems redundant. I guess both would work though.

Comment: In the firebase docs they use await, that's why I wanted to show an example with await.

Comment: @Wolfgang understandable, definitely still a very viable answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

In Typescript, you don't need to specify the promise return type precisely. Here's an example of how to use promise handlers with setDoc:

```
import { doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

setDoc(doc(database, `path`), objData)
  .then((data) => {console.log('data', data);})
  .catch((err) => {console.log('err', err);})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some odd behavior. I'm making a handler function in Angular that calls a Firebase Cloud Function that writes to Firestore. I'm using the emulator.

*app.component.ts*

```js
  wordRequest(word: string, l2Language: L2Language, requestOrigin: string) {
    const buildWordObject = httpsCallableFromURL(this.functions, 'http://localhost:5001/my-app/us-central1/buildWordObject');
    buildWordObject({
      word: word,
      l2Language: l2Language,
      requestOrigin: requestOrigin
    })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.data);
        if (result.data === null) {
          console.log("Success! Word object written to database.");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

*index.js*

```js
export const buildWordObject = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    ...does various stuff here

    setDoc(doc(firestore, 'Dictionaries/' + longLanguage + '/Words', word), wordObject)
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Finished writing word object to Firestore database: " + word);
            return 37
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
            console.error(error);
            return error
        });
    return 38
});
```

This logs `Finished writing word object to Firestore database: luck` in the emulator console and logs `38` in the Angular console.

If I comment out `return 38` the emulator log is the same but in the Angular console I see:

```
Success! Word object written to database.
```

Either way the data is written to the Firestore emulator.

A successful database write returns `null` to the Angular handler function that called it. I don't see `Success!` for a few seconds so it's clearly doing something async.

If I comment out `return 37` and `return error` then everything runs without errors. Usually when I write a Firebase Cloud Function without a return statement it throws an error in the log.

What I find odd is that the return to the Angular handler is always `null`, never `37`. The `console.log` message writes to the emulator log but the `return 37` statement never executes. You can't return anything but `null` back to the calling function.

I tried putting `.finally(() => { return 37 });` at the end but I never got `37` back.